# Fast App Switch iOS 11 Facebook Login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Currently my facebook login does the following:

1. Tap the login with fb button
2. Asks for permission to to use "facebook.com" to log in
3. Asks whether to use app or log in with an email or phone in a Safari View Controller
4. If selected app: Asks to open Facebook app
5. Asks for permission to let the fb app use your to log in
6. Returns to app

Those are too many steps for me. I'd like to do something like Uber app, it's facebook login flow is:

1. Tap the login with fb button
2. Asks to open Facebook app
3. Asks for permission to let the fb app use your account to log in
4. Returns to app

Uber's flow:
[image: uber flow]

### Facebook Fast App Switch

There's an article that says theres a [Fast App Switch](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/) way to login which is what I want for my app, If facebook app is installed I want the login to be done directly to the app.

I've used this code at my sign in button action with no luck:

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .native

fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in

    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)

    // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs..
}
```

At my **Info.plist**:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbXXXXXXXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>XXXXXXXX</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>My Beautiful App</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

At my **AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return handled
}
```

**Facebook SDK version:** 4.27.1

*Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.27.1)*
*FBSDKLoginKit (4.27.1)*
*FBSDKShareKit (4.27.1)*